# relative path in Django settings

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

I have a Django Project in Eclipse (PyDev). 
I am having troubles trying to set the NAME property of the DATABSE entry in the settings.py file. The problem is it seems it needs an absolute path but I would strongly prefer to set a path relative to the Eclipse workspace/project.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [os.path.abspath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath), [os.path.dirname](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname), [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) `__file__` attribute of the module.

For example, the following code will return absolute path of the db file which exists at the same directory that containing `settings.py`:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'dbfile.sqlite3')
```